# Xcode warning: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s):arm, arm (-19031)

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, warnings

I've been receiving this warning since I loaded my project in last Xcode 4 preview. There was no warning before that but now I can't get rid of it even in Xcode 3.2. I've been googling but nobody seems to have the same error.

My project and target settings are correct (IMHO): Architectures: Standard (armv6 armv7), Base SDK: Latest iOS (currently set to iOS 4.2), Build Active Architecture Only: FALSE, Valid Architectures: armv6 armv7.

I compared every project setting with other projects and and found no differences. I even have recreated the project starting from scratch and copying classes, resources and frameworks with the same result.

I must say that the warning is not shown when I set Debug configuration.

I hope someone can help me because I don't know what to do. Thanks in advice.

Comment: You say you've recreated the project from scratch, copied the source over, and still get the same issue? Perhaps you could try copying them over one-at-a-time and isolate exactly what part causes it to happen.

Comment: But I guess the source code can not generate this error. Am I right?. I mean, this seems a compiler error to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I kept getting this error and it was driving me crazy. Then I realized I was building the project for Simulator instead of Device. Once I made the change, I was able to upload the app without a problem.

Comment: yep, same to me. select Distribution and Device

Comment: Yes, this is the same thing that happened to me Thanks simplyDusty

Answer (score 0):

Several things spring to mind. Firstly that there is some file lurking around in the build directory. But I presume you have deleted the build directory. Secondly, that there is something lurking in your library directories. I think xcode puts some tempt files down in them now. Thirdly that something has gone funny is the core xcode setup.

So here's what I would try (the emphasis here is "try" - I don't know if any of this will work :-)

1. Make sure you have deleted the build directory.
2. Do a full un-installation of code. Clear out any developer directories and then re-install.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Of course deleting the build directory was my first try. I recently updated Xcode to last version too but, most important, I don't get the warning if I build any other project so it must be something related to this particular project.

Comment: OK, I have more info related to my problem. I recently realized that the warning only appears when the Distribuition scheme is active. So I've delete this preset, duplicate the Release profile and add the code-sign with my distribuition certificate and I got the same warning. When I change the code-signature to iPhone Developer everything is ok so the problem is the iPhone Distribuition code signing identity. I suspect that I retrieved that certificate while I was testing Xcode 4 (although I don't remember actually) and now it messed up a bit.

Comment: Anyway, I've been able to upload my app to Apple (including the warning) and I'm now waiting for review.

Comment: Well. It happened again. I have received same warning while working with another project but now Organizer don't let me upload my app because of this. I have uninstalled both xcode4 beta5 and xcode3.2 and reinstalled just the last xcode 3.2 but nothing changed. I'm starting to panic. Worst of all, I can't find anybody with the same problem nor info while I search Google. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!. Not a good solution though.

After a thousand tests I uninstalled Xcode 3.2.5 and installed 3.2.4. Everything went ok since then. Now I'm afraid of upgrade to last version again. :/